# Isolation distance between tracks with focus on ESD

Tags: layout, esd, tvs, routing

I am working on a product which has to meet:

- 8kV IEC 61000-4-2 contact discharge
- 4kV IEC 61000-4-4 transients
- 1.2kV/500Ohm IEC 61000-4-5 Surges

**The schematic:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmAQHf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transreceiver meets - per specification - the requirements in the given circuit without any external components other than the capacitor.

**My problem is:**

As I am working on a extremly space constrained design, there is no routing space to separate the incoming tracks (connector too transreceiver) from the internal logic signals - at least not more than approximately 250um.

The areas of close proximity are also rather close to the connector - so "far" away from the transreceiver.

This makes me believe that the ESD-events will couple into the internal tracks before they are "clamped" by the ESD-protection,  thereby bypassing/degrading the protection.

To illustrate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Rne6.png)</sup>

Will this routing affect the ESD-Protection or is it sound?

Are there any standards or "rules-of-thumb" in regard to track spacing under these circumstances?

**Edit 1:**

This is the specific layout in question:
[image]

The green and yellow (not the best highlighting) track is the external Signal in question.

In the areas circled red, it runs close too internal logic signals (I am not worried about running close to GND - or should i?).
After jumping a layer (See via in yellow track on the right side),
the track reaches the transreceiver pad after aprox. 5mm.

Comment: Are you concerned about the integrity of the connector-transceiver path, or interference with nearby signals?  Do you have a tentative layout you could share screenshots of?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your response. I am concernd, that routing "internal" and "external" tracks in close proximity will degrade the ESD-protection in regard to the "externel signals". In short: Will ESD events jump over/couple over - and therefore degrade the ESD-Protection rating (provided by the transreceiver) - compared to routing the tracks seperated widely?

I will update the question with layout images in a moment.

Comment: These are pretty common requirements. In case there's nothing between the connector and the IC that can be harmed, then I don't understand what the problem is. The discharge will be against the connector pin, not against the traces... assuming your PCB has a solder mask.

Comment: @Lundin I am worried about capacitive coupling/other forms of coupling due too the small seperation and the fast ESD rise-times.